# Vaadin 14 radiobuttongroup display custom Strings as options

Tags: java, radio-button, vaadin, vaadin14

I am using Vaadin 14.1.21 + Java JDK/JRE 1.8

I have a single-select radiobuttongroup with a boolean field behind it in the DataClass.

I don't want to display "true" / "false" as options for the user, but custom Strings, let's say "red option" for true and "green option" for false.

I see in the API that there is a function called setRenderer, but I am not sure how to use it. I already figured out how to do it in a grid, but not on the selection box...

**Selection box (todo):**

```
rbgroup = new RadioButtonGroup<>();
rbgroup.setRequired(true);
rbgroup.setLabel("Title of radiobuttongroup");
rbgroup.setItems(true, false); // how to display them in the frontend as "Green option" / "Red option"?

....

binder.forField(rbgroup).bind("mybooleanField");
```

**Grid: (done)**

```
addColumn((mn) -> { // custom display
            final String displayAS;
            if (mn.getBoolValue()) {
                displayAS = "Option Red";
            } else {
                displayAS = "Option Green";
            }
            return displayAS;
        })
.setHeader("Columntitle")
.setFlexGrow(1)
.setSortable(true)
.setKey("Color Option");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is shown in the [code examples of RadioButtonGroup](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-radio-button/java-examples), setting a renderer to show text can be done like this (mix between example code and your code):

```
RadioButtonGroup<Boolean> rbgroup = new RadioButtonGroup<>();
rbgroup.setRequired(true);
rbgroup.setLabel("Title of radiobuttongroup");
rbgroup.setItems(true, false);
rbgroup.setRenderer(new TextRenderer<>((mn) -> {
    if (mn) {
        return "Option Red";
    } else {
        return "Option Green";
    }
}));
```

If you want to display any Vaadin Component instead of only Text, you can use a `ComponentRenderer` instead of a `TextRenderer`. I use a simple `Span` as example but you could build complex Layouts and return those instead.

```
RadioButtonGroup<Boolean> rbgroup = new RadioButtonGroup<>();
rbgroup.setRequired(true);
rbgroup.setLabel("Title of radiobuttongroup");
rbgroup.setItems(true, false);
rbgroup.setRenderer(new ComponentRenderer<>((mn) -> {
    if (mn) {
        return new Span("Option Green");
    } else {
        return new Span("Option Red");
    }
}));
```